# Make character and plane interact in pose mode?

Tags: pose-mode

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fOs4cfkD9Pmj4wb4plDLNib-LdbA9WnN/view?usp=sharing

Attached is my file. I have my rigid body constraints set up so that when I press play it sort of... kind of interacts with it? The character clips through the plane until the calve legs, then collides, and that's one problem.

But what I want to figure out is, how do I make my character collide with the plane in pose mode? I'm trying to make a running cycle and want the feet to stop and bend at it when they touch instead of clipping through. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In pose mode you manually position a bone at a certain position at a specific frame. With physics simulations like rigid body, the simulation positions items over time.

You cannot use physics to control a bone while you are manually positioning it in pose mode. You need to visually position the bones while creating keyframes, this is often best done from the camera view to ensure the desired visual result.

You can bake a physics simulation into keyframes and then manually adjust some of the generated keyframes.

You cannot mix keyframe animation and simulations at the same time, you use one or the other. Some physics can be turned on and off at specific keyframes allowing you to use both at different times during the animation. This is commonly used to animate an initial velocity of an item at the time the physics begins.